# Percentage axis ticks

Tags: plotting

To create a percentage axe in some plot I use this `Ticks` configuration:

```
ListPlot[
     Range[0,1,0.1]
    ,Ticks->{Automatic, {#,If[IntegerPart@Mod[100#,10]==0,Row[{100#,"%"}],""]}&/@Range[0,1,0.05]}
]
```

[image]

That has 3 disadvantage:

1. Non automatic range scale
2. No subticks with different sizes
3. It's nor elegant nor simple

I miss a Mathematica `TicksFunction` or equivalent, so I could have better control over it. I also tried something like: `ListPlot[Quantity[Range[0, 1, 0.1], "Percent"]]` without succes.

Some clue into a better approach?

Comment: Why not just relabelling the ticks ?

Comment: How can I do this? Using...

Comment: Define `pc = {#, ToString[100 #] <> " %"} & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1]` and then `Ticks -> {Automatic, pc}`.

Comment: tks, but in this way you remove the subticks.

Comment: Would it fit to your approach to use the label, i.e. somethin like `AxesLabel -> {"your x-axis label", "something in %"} and leave the `TicksLabels` as they are (and hence keep the `MinorTicks` ?

Comment: Perhaps the new unit handling / plotting features in V9 can be of some use?

Comment: Hi @YvesKlett!.. I played with `ListPlot[Quantity[Range[0, 1, 0.1], "Percent"]]`. No nice result.

Comment: @Murta yeah, `ListPlot[Quantity[Range[0, 1, 0.1], "Percent"], 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]` rather predictably labels "just" the axes properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica 9, I developed a PercentTicks function to solve this problem. Here is an example of how it is used:

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, x}, {x, 0, .003, 0.0001}], 
         Ticks -> { Automatic, PercentTicks }]
```

which gives:

[image: PercentTicks example]

The code is [in my github repo](https://github.com/deansher/Mathematica-Utility-Packages/blob/master/MyFormatters.m).

Comment: Nice code. Tks.

Answer (score 9):

Replace the automatically generated labels to not have to care about generating the ticks yourself and preserve subticks:

```
percentTicks[plot_] := Module[{xticks, yticks},
  {xticks, yticks} = (Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks]);
  yticks = 
   yticks /. {y_, lbl_, rest__} /; lbl != "" :> {y, ToString[y*100] <> "%", rest};
  Show[plot, Ticks -> {xticks, yticks}]
  ]

percentTicks@ListPlot[Sort@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This _theoretically_ works OK, but M version 8 has a bug and `AbsoluteOptions` doesn't work as expected for _Ticks_

Comment: @belisarius Got more details on that bug? I have v8 but can't break it.

Comment: Take a look at the x-axis ticks http://i.stack.imgur.com/T7kbm.png

Comment: It is v 8.0 BTW

Comment: It's not simple, but I agree it's the best that can be done with MMA until version 9. Tks! 1+

Comment: Is it possible to prevent the conversion of integers to reals with this method?

Comment: @shrx you can try throwing in `Round` on the `y*100` part

Comment: Do not work in V10

Answer (score 3):

You can take control of all relevant bits :

```
pcTicks = {#, ToString[100 #] <> " %", {0.02, 0}} & /@  Range[0, 1, 0.1];
pcSubTicks = {#, "", {0.01, 0}} & /@ (Range[0, 1, 0.1] + 0.05);

ListPlot[Range[0, 1, 0.1], Ticks -> {Automatic, Join[pcTicks, pcSubTicks]}]
```

[image]