# How to plot an Operating Characteristic Curve using Hypergeometric distribution?

Tags: plotting

I"m trying to plot an OC curve (y-axis Probability of acceptance, x-axis Lot Percent Defective) and there should be a way to plot using a hypergeometric distribution.

```
In[117]:= NProbability[x <= 0, 
 x \[Distributed] HypergeometricDistribution[8, 7, 500]]

Out[117]= 0.89262
```

is great for one point. The 7 in the distribution is the number defective in the lot of 500, I'd like to plot this for 1, 2, etc. Then alter the x-axis labels to represent the percent defective in the lot of 500, .1%, 1%, 2%, etc....

I can get the individual values as above, yet not able to get a plot.

I can do this using `PoissonDistribution`

```
Plot[{N[Probability[x <= 0, 
    x \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[13*lpd]]], 
  N[Probability[x <= 0, 
    x \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[8*lpd]]]}, {lpd, 0, .5}]
```

which assumes a very large lot size. I have the situation with smaller lot sizes and using hypergeometric is the right way to do the calculation for the OC curve - just not able to sort out the plotting.

Any suggestions?

cheers,

Fred

Comment: `DiscretePlot` is good for plotting discrete functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `Ticks` option you can set custom ticks, [see this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17803/percentage-axis-ticks):

```
DiscretePlot[
 Probability[x <= 0, x \[Distributed] HypergeometricDistribution[8, d, 500]],
 {d, 0, 250},
 Ticks -> {Table[{i 500/100, ToString@i <> "%"}, {i, 0, 50, 5}],Automatic}
]
```

[image]

Comment: This is right on what I was trying to do. Excellent.

Comment: Ok, now is it possible to easily adjust the x-axis ticks to show correct lot percent defective when I change the number of units sampled and the lot size?

I apparently do not understanding the Ticks element and how it is constructed as I'm not able to alter it and get meaningful results.

cheers,

Fred